# problems using position fixed

Tags: css

The problem is though that header's top margin is ignored as long as topBar has position:fixed (So when the page loads, header is pretty much hidden below topBar).

How do I fix margin-top being ignored?

Thanks in advace..

Comment: try margin-top:height of top-bar; otherwise give some code

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from your question you are trying to give position:fixed only to topBar. Please find my pseudo code to answer your problem.Try adding position fixed to the outer header container so that both the top bar and header stays fixed.

```
 <header style="position:fixed;">
   <nav class="top-bar">
   </nav>
 </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this if problem is still remain then share code

```
#header
{
position:fixed;
top:0px;
width:100%;
height:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the header's top margin to the desired value plus the height of topBar.